# Looping through arrays and checking their values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

What I have done is that I have firstly I have parsed them with the jQuery function, `$.parseJSON()` and so now I am having 2 arrays with 3 objects inside them. What I want to do is that I want to loop over both the arrays at the same time so that I could check the `Post_ID`s of the current object in the loop of both the arrays that if they are equal or not and then if I find that the `Post_ID` is not present there already or there is a mismatch then I want to do something.

Here's what I have done:

```
var posts = <? php echo $posts; ?> ;
setInterval(function () {
    $.get("admin/post/get_new_posts.php", {
        userId: <? php echo User::GetUserID($_SESSION["username"]); ?>
    }, function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < posts.length; j++) {
                if (posts[j].Post_ID != data[i].Post_ID) {
                    //do something...
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    });
}, 10000);
```

The `posts` variable has its value and I am sure about it by logging them into the console. Now what happens here is that every ten seconds a get request is sent and checks if the Post_ID meets of the `posts` variable object does not equal the `Post_ID` of the `data` variable then do something in there. But that's not the case. The condition is always going true.

And yes, here are my objects. The first one is the `posts` variable and the second one is the `data` variable.

[image: the posts and data variables view]

Any idea of how can I loop through both the variables or arrays and check for a property at the same time while looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing *every* entry in `posts` to *every* entry in `data`. Most of those won't match - `posts[0]` won't match `data[1]`, `data[2]`, etc.

It sounds like you want to look at the corresponding members of each list (`posts[0]` vs. `data[0]`, etc.)

In that case, you need one loop, not two.

```
// find the longest array's length
var maxi = Math.max(posts.length, data.length, 0);

for ( var i = 0; i < maxi; ++i )
{
  if (i >= posts.length)
  {
    // an entry in data, but not posts
  }
  else if (i >= data.length)
  {
    // an entry in posts, but not data
  }
  else if (data[i].Post_ID != posts[i].Post_ID)
  {
    // mismatched IDs
  }
  else
  {
    // matched IDs
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing two loops and this creates a problem. because they have the following meaning (I'm gonna translate them into pure english): 
for each item of array 'data', check any item in array 'posts' that is not equal to the current item of 'data'. This is why it is always "doing something".

Since both arrays have the same length, you should do one loop like this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (posts[i].Post_ID != data[i].Post_ID) {
                //do something...
            } else {

            }
    }
```